# moving eclipse (not the workspace) to a different directory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I recently installed Mars Eclipse.  I took the default install directory, c:\users\myname\eclipse\java-mars.  Everything is installed and some projects checked out and working.

But I now wish I had installed it in c:\eclipse\java-mars.  I am wondering how to change it?  Please note I did searches but they all are how to move your workspace, not how to change the installation directory.  My workspace can stay where it is.  I suppose I could uninstall and delete everything, and reinstall into a new directory, but that is a lot of hassle.

Comment: Of course you can uninstall and re-install it. And it's no hassle believe in me. Otherwise you can just copy your installation directory to another place. That kinda work.

Comment: you can copy your eclipse from c:\users\myname\eclipse\java-mars to c:\eclipse\java-mars.

Comment: That will work?  Won't have to update variables and things like that?

Comment: Actually I got an error The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.  Do I need to add something to the PATH (this is Windows 7) and library directories?

Comment: Eclipse isn't really "installed" since you just download a zip file, and extract it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move the eclipse folder to the new location. There's no need to change anything in the PATH variable because this thing is only needed by eclipse itself to locate the java environment.

*Note:

If you have any third-party librarys inside the eclipse folder that are used by eclipse during it's runtime there may be an error because eclipse only stores an absolute path to them in it's config files. So in that case, you have to change the path to such libraries in the eclipse settings, I think at the same point where you have added them.*

Comment: Thanks.  I did get this error though when I tried to move it:

"The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."